# How to extend a core class(Array) in a new user defined class

Tags: ruby

In ruby console when we type

```
a = String.new('cool')
'cool'
```

Likewise for array

```
b = Array.new([1,2,3,4])
[1,2,3,4]
```

I need to do something like the following

```
class NewArray < Array

  def initialize(something)
    # doing some action with something
    # and construct and array like
    [1,2,3,4,5]
  end
  ...
end
```

Now when I call this from the console

```
a = NewArray.new(something)
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Till now I am getting something like

```
a = NewArray.new(something)
#<NewArray:0x00000aab5fe>
a
#<NewArray:0x00000aab5fe>
```

**UPDATE**
changed `NewArray(something)` to `NewArray.new(something)`

Comment: NewArray is not a method, so why are you trying to send it an argument?  Are you  actually getting what you say you are getting with line `a = NewArray(something)` or are you getting an error?

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to never inherit from core classes.(unless you really know what you are are doing) [A Reference](http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes) but there are many more.
You can however get the functionality you want through the `SimpleDelegator` class like so

```
 require 'delegate'
 class NewArray < SimpleDelegator; end

 NewArray.new([1,2,3])
 #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

[`SimpleDelegator` Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html)

Comment: @mgs it is also important to note that when you want to initialize a new _instance_ of a class, you must call `ClassName.new()`. Otherwise, `NewArray(something)` is read as `some_method(param)`. It is best to keep method and object names `lower_snake_case`, class names `UpperCamelCase`, and constants `CAPITALIZED`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to send an argument to a name such as NewArray, you will need to define it as a method.

```
def NewArray(something)
  [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
end
puts NewArray('anything')
```

This is not that common to do, but it is done for methods like Integer and Array and a few others on Kernel module.